# PHP 'Trying to get property of non-object' with static class member

Tags: php, static-members

I have a class that displays ads on a page.  I want to keep track of which ads have been displayed so I added a private static member to the class which will hold an array of numbers.  I want to add IDs from a db query result to the static member as a way to exclude those IDs from the next query.  This would prevent a displayed ad from being displayed again on the same page.

```
class ADS {
    private static $excluded_ads = array();

    function get_ads() {
        // run db query and assign $ads to the resulting array
        $ads = $this->query();

        // Iterate through result and add the IDs of each row to the static array
        foreach ($ads as $ad) {
            self::$excluded_ads[] = $ad->ID;
        }
    }

    function query() {
        // Use local variable to hold string of excluded ads
        $excluded_ads = $this->sql_get_excluded_ads();

        // run the db query and use the class static member to exclude results
        // SELECT * FROM ....
        // WHERE ...
        // AND p.ID NOT IN ($excluded_ads)
    }

    function sql_get_excluded_ads() {
        if (empty(self::$excluded_ads)){
            return '-1';
        } else {
            return implode(',',self::$excluded_ads);
        }
    }
}

$ads_class = new ADS();
$ads_class->get_ads();
```

When I load the page I get this error `Trying to get property of non-object` for the line `self::$excluded_ads[] = $ad->ID;`

Do static class members work this way in PHP?  I know this value will get reset on each page load - but that is the functionality I want.  I want this to contain values only for the current page/process and then reset.

Comment: that error has nothing to do with your static variable it has to do with your `$ad` variable, its saying its not an object are you sure `query()` returns an array of objects?

Comment: Shouldn't `$excluded_ads = sql_get_excluded_ads();` in `query()` be `self::$excluded_ads = $this->sql_get_excluded_ads();`

Comment: Looks like you query result is not what you expecting. Check results of `var_dump($ads);`.

Comment: Thanks for the var_dump($ads) suggestion.  It turned out that my query wasn't returning data structured in the way I thought it was and seeing the dump showed as much.  I changed my query and my debug dumps started displaying the values I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you tryed debug what is in var_dump($ads)?

Comment: please do not add comments as answers, i know you do not have rep to comment but still should not try to circumvent that by adding it as an answer